# auto mathematical operations on same row and next row using jquery in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

Hi i have a table saving it by doing sum mathematical operations. and the same table i'm fetching the data and displaying it. but the problem is after displaying the table, if i change the value in a particular field then same mathematical operations must done automatically and then after i can save that table.

I'm using first picture as a view to show the installment

the second picture is the installments table.

[image]

[image]

So if i change one field value in principle Installment (8th column). then the next two column values must change ( mathematical operations must be done using the previous row field values) and the next row values also must change( using this row field values).

can anyone help me plz

Comment: You will have to do calculations in View and Controller / Business both. You may save data from Controller / Business only. This also depends on if you're using AJAX or not. Your question is not very clear!

Comment: i don't want to do it in view or controller. i want it in jquery. if i change a value in one row of principal Installment column. then based on that value remaining field values should be calculated there itself and show.

Comment: in a way jQuery is a part of the view itself :) If you are doing the calculation using jQuery, what is the problem then?

Comment: i don't know how to write the code in jquery. i'm looking for some one will help me